# Why Sublime Text 2 highlights in white everything with no reason

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

It is really annoying. I do not know if it's because I installed something, or what? But suddenly sublime text began to select all php variables or html tags in white for no reason. I've tried turn it off but I have no idea how :(

[image]

When I open some the file, the code is ok but whenever I edit anything, even without saving, it immediately become marked white :(

Comment: See if changing color scheme fixes this. Maybe something in the current theme might have changed.

Comment: No it's still white :(

Comment: What does the statusbar say which syntax highlighting you use? At the bottom right it should mention it.

Comment: It happen in evryone in PHP, Python (Colorcode), HTML(Erlang) ....

Comment: What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: disable all your plugins.

Comment: Ok! I turned off one after the other a few plugins and found that it "ColorCoder" was guilty. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: You can mark your question as answered if you found out what caused it.