# SublimeText 3: HTML tags being highlighted gray after switching apps

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3, color-scheme

Just made the jump to Sublime Text 3 and installed all my old tweaks, packages, themes etc.

One weird thing I'm getting that I can't figure out is that when I load an HTML file, switch apps then switch back, the tags get highlighted gray.

Here's the before:

[image]

Here's what happens when I switch apps then come back:

[image]

Switched themes and color schemes, deleted packages and it still happens. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I remember someone having a similar problem in ST2 and [posting this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559658/why-sublime-text-2-highlights-in-white-everything-with-no-reason) not long ago. Maybe the two of you can figure this out, see what packages you both have installed.

Comment: What packages do you have installed?

Comment: Here are my packages: "Alignment",
"AutoFileName",
"BracketHighlighter",
"Color Highlighter",
"Colorcoder",
"ColorPicker",
"CSS Format",
"DocBlockr",
"Emmet",
"FileDiffs",
"GitGutter",
"HTML-CSS-JS Prettify",
"HTMLBeautify",
"Sass",
"SassBeautify",
"SCSS",
"SideBarEnhancements",
"SublimeCodeIntel",
"SublimeLinter",
"SublimeLinter-csslint",
"SublimeLinter-html-tidy",
"SublimeLinter-jshint",
"SublimeLinter-php",
"Theme - Soda"

Comment: @idleberg, yes! same problem. did you ever solve the problem?

Comment: @user2384202 try adding "Color Highlighter", "Colorcoder", and "ColorPicker" to the `ignored_packages` setting of your user preferences (`Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings-User`), saving the file, then restarting Sublime and seeing if that does the trick. If not, add "BracketHighlighter" to the list just for fun. It has to be valid JSON, so make sure you have a comma `,` after every item except the last one. If that works, take each one out of the list one at a time until the behavior comes back - the last one removed is the one causing the problem.

Comment: @MattDMo it was color coder! many thanks!